# Creating calculated column

Tags: mysql, functions, count

I want to create a rating weight and I need do calculate AVG, then find COUNT and multiply both to get weight. I have something like that:

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(CASE WHEN vote > 0 THEN vote ELSE NULL END) AS voters,
AVG(CASE WHEN vote > 0 THEN vote ELSE NULL END) AS average FROM wp_imdb_rating
GROUP BY post_id 
ORDER BY voters * average DESC
LIMIT 0, 100
```

But it says:

> #1247 - Reference 'voters' not supported (reference to group function)

I can order by **average** and **voters** separately, but I can't combine them with any formula. How can I use a formula in order clause that includes values from AVG and COUNT?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to replace the aliases with full formulas - `ORDER BY COUNT(CASE WHEN vote > 0 THEN vote ELSE NULL END) * AVG(CASE WHEN vote > 0 THEN vote ELSE NULL END)` - either it will work or you might get some other error message, hopefuly more helpful this time.

Comment: Any chance `wp_imdb_rating` is a view?

Comment: @jkavalik I was working on a script similar to imdb. I have post_id, user_id and vote columns inside wp_imdb_rating table. I applied formula that imdb uses in its top system to define movie rating weight. What else infromation you specially want I can post here.

Comment: Nothing more needed. I just had some idea where the limitation might come from and wanted to check. If the full expression is allowed but the aliases no, then it might be imho classified as a bug? From what I gathered there used to be limitations which did not allow even the *full* version, so maybe the check was just not fully removed? But just guessing here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be some old limitation of the optimizer maybe, aliases to aggregating expressions are not allowed in more complex expressions in ORDER BY.

You can get around it by using the full expression instead of the alias:

```
ORDER BY
    COUNT(CASE WHEN vote > 0 THEN vote ELSE NULL END)
  *
    AVG(CASE WHEN vote > 0 THEN vote ELSE NULL END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, probably with the same performance:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT post_id,
               COUNT(IF(vote > 0, vote, NULL) AS voters,
               AVG(IF(vote > 0, vote, NULL) AS average
            FROM wp_imdb_rating
            GROUP BY post_id 
          )
    ORDER BY voters * average DESC
    LIMIT 0, 100
```

Note:  Whenever `ORDER BY` is not the same as the `GROUP BY`, there *will* be a "filesort".

Comment: I already used expressions instead of aliases but thanks, this solution works too.